# What is .htmb extension?

Tags: html, url, file-extension

Today, I found a web page as following structure. It is just look like a `.html` page, but extension of that page is `.htmb`.

```
http://example.com/name.htmb
```

I googled also, but I coundn't get any information about `.htmb` extension.

Comment: I saw this question, googled "htmb extension", and was directed right back here.  I might be able to help if you post a little more context.  Where did you encounter this extension?

Comment: @JonathanWilson http://www.list.lk/solutions/translation-services.htmb This is the URL, seems like it is it is related to htaccess file because even I change the extention for any other one still page is loading without 404.....

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a simple typo!  If you change `htmb` to `html`, you will see a web page about translation services.

http://www.list.lk/solutions/translation-services.html

Comment: I think it is now our duty to create and publicize the `htmb` file extension.  What should we use it for?

Answer (score 0):

It's an extension used in the (abandoned) Lighty2Go webserver, for details see their site:

http://www.lighty2go.com/ (abandoned?)

https://pendriveapps.com/lighty2go-portable-limp-web-server/

Seems to be a Xonobasic executable:

```
".htmb" => var.l2gDir + "/xonobasic/xonobasic.exe"
```

as per this post: http://xonocode.com/forum/showthread.php?mode=linear&tid=4&pid=4

HTH!!